# Buttons make my multiview iphone app crash! (but single view is okay)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is probably some rookie mistake, but I can't figure it out. I've established a button within my app to recall a link in safari. From my method file it looks like this:

Obj C Code:

```
-(IBAction)linkSafari{

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/"]];
}
```

I linked it up in IB and all seems okay.

When I create this same setup as a single view app it works great, but whenever I click it in my multiview app it's an automatic crash. Acts the same way on both my simulator and physical ipod.

Is there an endless list of places I could have screwed up or is there a certain area I should look into?

Comment: 1st thing to look into is crash log - you can likely find the error message there

Comment: I'm very new. Can you point me to the crash log?

Comment: If you run your application in debug mode then you'll be able to see call stack and error message will be printed to console (you can see it using menu run/console or shift-cmd-R shortcut). You can also see device crash logs in organizer window (menu windows/organizer)

Comment: Ah, got it. My error is SIGABRT. Also, this is my general overview: http://screenr.com/Tnr

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is in that particular function, 
but on the way you create the views and viewcontrollers

Comment: I think you're right, but I don't know how to determine where the issue lies.

Comment: this is rather vague but try making a multiview application example where the buttons only perform a dummy NSLog call. once you have the multiview framework working you can start doing some other stuff.

there are some easy tutorials in youtube

Comment: that being the case, you are gonna have to debug you application, the call stack window will definitively help

http://macdevelopertips.com/xcode/xcode-debugging-reset-current-line.html

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, this was solved thanks to an extra set of eyes. On my tab bar, I'd declared the assigned nibs for every section, but missed a few class associations. That's what messed me up.